# Why does the scroll icon appear when I use a <span> in my HTML code?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to use a span element to style some text, but for some reason when I enter that code it will on the right side of the page show that scroll bar. It's not like that default scroll bar you will find on Google Chrome; it's really short, and when I move it it moves my text up and down for some reason.

I don't know how to fix that. I have tried reducing the padding, adding `<br>` at the end, etc.

This is the code:

```html
<p>And that's it! You can play around a bit more with CSS and then move to <span style="background-color: orange; color: #fff; padding: 2px;">Day 4 - Text Areas & Input Fields</span> for further lessons!</p>
```

I have restricted my text to a border on the page, so it looks better, but it can't have anything to do with my problem since I haven't had it before and I've been using this border tactic for a while now. And as well I know the button "My other articles" isn't linked to anything--I'll add the link later. I just need help with this one problem.

Thanks to whomever helps me out with this in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble with some non-standard terminology. What does "restricted my text to a border on the page" mean? Can you fix the snippet to show the problem? I suspect is has more to do with what's _around_ this paragraph than the paragraph itself.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the query completely. Do you have "overflow-y" style attribute somewhere in the parent element or somewhere?

Comment: This code is not reproducing your issue, can you please add more HTML / CSS

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be rendering correctly for me (Chrome on Linux):

[image: A render of the page working as expected]

I'd suggest you update your answer with [a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/) of what's happening.

The best thing to try in this scenario is to add the following CSS to your code if it's not working for you:

```
span {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Since you're doing inline CSS (you don't appear to have a linked stylesheet), you probably want something like this as your full code:

```html
<p>And that's it! You can play around a bit more with CSS and then move to <span style="background-color: orange; color: #fff; padding: 2px; overflow: visible;">Day 4 - Text Areas & Input Fields</span> for further lessons!</p>
```

`overflow: visible;` ensures that the element doesn't show scrollbars. In most cases (such as if this rule is applied to a `<div>`), then text inside the element will visually overflow if the element is a fixed size. The `<span>` isn't a fixed size (it grows as text is added), and so text won't appear as overflowing. Hopefully, though, it should solve the scrollbar problem.

Alternatively, you could try using `overflow: hidden;` which will hide the overflow entirely. Try experimenting with either `visible` or `hidden` and see if your code works!

More info about `overflow`: [overflow - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

---

> It's not like that default scroll bar you will find on Google Chrome; it's really short, and when I move it it moves my text up and down for some reason.

Try also applying the CSS to the `<p>` element as well/instead, or even the `<body>`. The `<span>` may or may not be the element that's experiencing the overflow issue, after all. Your question is admittedly worded quite vaguely for us to tell how the problem manifests.

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer, it was someone else, I was busy until now, so I'll check what you said right away.. 

I have tested it out, it doesn't help, I will provide a screenshot of my issue, hope it helps! I just don't know how to paste an image over here.. :(

Comment: Ok, nvm I have figured it out, since my padding was 2px, and I bordered my text and everything on the site with a border, it didn't have enough space to fit the <span> so I just added to <br><br> and it fixed it. Thanks anyways for trying to help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out in the end! Yeah, it's strange why someone downvoted the answer, but hey.